# How to add a method to an external class at runtime in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, methods

[PyGithub](http://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis.html) does not appear to support the [GitHub API call to acquire the latest release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release).  I'm wondering if I can add a method to PyGithub at run time that would do this for me.

For example, the existing code has the following method:

```
# Repository.py
def get_releases(self):
    """
    :calls: `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases <http://developer.github.com/v3/repos>`_
    :rtype: :class:`github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList` of :class:`github.Tag.Tag`
    """
    return github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList(
        github.GitRelease.GitRelease,
        self._requester,
        self.url + "/releases",
        None
    )
```

I'd like to add this one to the Repository.py class:

```
def get_latest_release(self):
    return github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList(
        github.GitRelease.GitRelease,
        self._requester,
        self.url + "/releases/latest",
        None
    )
```

I tried this but I received an error:

```
# main.py

from types import MethodType
from github import Github
from github.Repository import Repository, github

def get_latest_release(self): ...

def main():
    Repository.method = MethodType(get_latest_release, None, Repository)
    g = Github(<my name>, <my password>)
    org = g.get_organization(<name of org>)
    repo = org.get_repo(<name of repository>)
    release = repo.get_latest_release()

    # AttributeError: 'Repository' object has no attribute 'get_latest_release'
```

Is it possible to add this method at runtime?

Comment: Why not create a child class of GitHub?

Comment: Why did you assign to `Repository.method`? Why `method`?

Comment: Wouldn't `Repository.get_latest_release = get_latest_release` be sufficient. You would only need `MethodType` if you were trying to assign to an instance, e.g. `repo.get_lastest_release = MethodType(get_latest_release, repo)`

Comment: DYZ, I could.  I'm just seeing if this is possible.
user2357112, I'm new to Python so this is likely incorrect.  I'm just piecing together some information about adding unbound methods to a class.

Comment: Although also I wonder why you need it to be a method at all. Why not just a standalone function that takes the repo as its argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning directly to `Repository.get_latest_release` should be sufficients, e.g.:

```
Repository.get_latest_release = get_latest_release
```

You would only need `MethodType` if you were trying to assign to an instance, e.g.

```
>>> import types
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
>>> a = A()
>>> A.one = lambda self: 1
>>> a.two = types.MethodType(lambda self: 2, a)
>>> a.one(), a.two()
(1, 2)
```

Where `class` assignment is available to all instances of that class, `instance` assignment is not:

```
>>> b = A()
>>> b.one()
1
>>> b.two()
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'two'
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank-you.